# Docker container connect to remote db through jump SSH tunnel

Tags: docker, ssh, docker-compose

I am trying to connect to remote SQL, in between we have jump server. Usually, I can access the db from datagrip once I ssh into jump server from bash. I am trying to connect to the remote db through docker container. I have tried different Docker hub images.

Jump server listens to local port 11433 and forwards remote sql db port 1433.

Here is my **docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'
services:
    test-db:
image: gsengun/flyway-mssql
volumes:
  - ./sql:/flyway/sql
command: localhost 11433 user Password db
container_name: testDb
```

Here is my **docker file**.

```
FROM calendar42/python-geos
COPY ./svc/requirements.txt /domain/requirements.txt
COPY ./requirements.txt /api/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -U pip
RUN pip install -r /api/requirements.txt
WORKDIR /api/svc/
```

I am not sure exactly, what I am missing any help or direction is appreciated.

Comment: What is url have you tried connecting? Are you trying to connect to db inside docker? Is it running locally?

Comment: It's a remote sql server hosted not hosted on docker.